# A complete WiX 3.6 bundle example bootstrapping a .NET 4 Client Profile

Tags: wix, wix3.6, bootstrapping, .net-client-profile

I tried to construct a working example of a WiX 3.6 installation script. We currently use WiX 3.5 and now we would like to begin installing the [.NET 4 Client Profile framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) as a pre-requisite for our [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file that our `product.wxs` script creates. WiX 3.6 seems like the best way forward.

Is there a functional example of how to do this with WiX 3.6?

Here is our 3.5 script we use today:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

    <!-- Version change handling -->
    <?define UpgradeCode="###############################"?>
    <?ifdef env.BUILD_NUMBER ?>
    <?define ProductVersion="2.6.$(env.BUILD_NUMBER).0"?>
    <?else ?>
    <?define ProductVersion="2.6.0.0"?>
    <?endif ?>

    <Product Id="*" Name="###############################" Language="1033" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="###############################" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

        <!-- Custom actions for this installer -->
        <Binary Id="###############################.dll" SourceFile="..\..\Libraries\###############################.CA.dll" />

        <!-- Kill ##### before installation begins -->
        <CustomAction Id="Kill#####ActionId" BinaryKey="###############################.dll" DllEntry="Kill#####Action" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="yes" Return="check" />
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="Kill#####ActionId" Before="InstallInitialize" />
        </InstallExecuteSequence>

        <!-- ADD/REMOVE Programs icon -->
        <Icon Id="##############.ico" SourceFile="D:\##############\Input_WIX\NonHeat\##############.exe" />
        <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="##############.ico" />
        <Property Id="ARPHELPLINK" Value="http://##############" />

        <!-- EULA agreement -->
        <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="D:\##############\Input_WIX\Heat\License.rtf" />

        <!-- Installer images -->
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="InstallerTopImage.rle" />
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="InstallerSideImage.rle" />
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
        <Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
            <UpgradeVersion Minimum="1.0.0.0" Maximum="99.0.0.0" Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" />
        </Upgrade>

        <!-- Require ##### to be installed -->
        <Property Id="#####4.INSTALLPATH">
            <RegistrySearch Id="RegistryFoundInstallPath" Key="SOFTWARE\McNeel\#####ceros\4.0" Root="HKLM" Name="InstallPath" Type="directory" />
        </Property>
        <Property Id="#####4.RECENT">
            <RegistrySearch Id="RegistryFoundMostRecent" Key="SOFTWARE\McNeel\#####ceros\4.0" Root="HKLM" Name="MostRecent" Type="raw" />
        </Property>
        <Property Id="VRAYCOMMONDIR">
            <RegistrySearch Id="ReigstryVRayCommon" Key="Software\ASGvis" Root="HKLM" Name="Common_dir" Type="raw" />
        </Property>
        <Condition Message="##### 4 required before install">
            #####4.RECENT
        </Condition>

        <!-- Require administrator priveleges -->
        <Condition Message="You need to be an administrator to install this product.">
            Privileged</Condition>

        <!-- Require .NET 3.5 SP1 to install -->
        <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL" />
        <Condition Message='This setup requires the .NET Framework 3.5 with Service Pack 1 be installed.'>
            <![CDATA[Installed OR (NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL AND NETFRAMEWORK35_SP_LEVEL = "#1")]]>
        </Condition>

        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="#####4.INSTALLPATH">
                <Directory Id="#####4.SYSTEM" Name="System"></Directory>
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="##############"></Directory>
                <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
                <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
                    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="##############" />
                </Directory>
            </Directory>

            <!-- Set FULL permissions to our shared folders -->
            <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
                <Directory Id="CommonApp##############" Name="##############">
                    <Directory Id="MODELLIBPATH" Name="##############">
                        <Component Id="##############UserPermissions" Guid="##############">
                            <CreateFolder>
                                <util:PermissionEx GenericRead="yes" GenericWrite="yes" GenericExecute="yes" Delete="yes" DeleteChild="yes" User="Users" Domain="[MachineName]" />
                            </CreateFolder>
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                    <Directory Id="APPDATAPATH" Name="#####">
                        <Component Id="##############UserPermissions" Guid="FC4BF85F-E7A4-45DE-B25C-8F9419E75307">
                            <CreateFolder>
                                <util:PermissionEx GenericRead="yes" GenericWrite="yes" GenericExecute="yes" Delete="yes" DeleteChild="yes" User="Users" Domain="[MachineName]" />
                            </CreateFolder>
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="FontsFolder"></Directory>
            <Component Id="##############RegistryKeys" Guid="17A55BEA-605D-425a-AAEE-F35EC8C1061E" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes">
                <RegistryValue Id="##############RegInstallDir" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\##############\##############" Name="InstallPath" Action="write" Type="string" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]" />
                <RegistryValue Id="##############RegLibraryPath" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\##############\##############" Name="LibraryPath" Action="write" Type="string" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]Library" />
                <RegistryValue Id="##############RegModelLibraryPath" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\##############\##############" Name="ModelLibraryPath" Action="write" Type="string" Value="[MODELLIBPATH]" />
                <RegistryKey Id="##############Reg#####PluginKey" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\McNeel\#####ceros\4.0\[#####4.RECENT]\Plug-ins\FCAF502A-1572-42a9-A2C3-F25D7953B1A5\PlugIn" Action="create" />
                <RegistryValue Id="##############RegName#####4" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\McNeel\#####ceros\4.0\[#####4.RECENT]\Plug-ins\FCAF502A-1572-42a9-A2C3-F25D7953B1A5" Name="Name" Action="write" Type="string" Value="##############Server" />
                <RegistryValue Id="##############Reg#####4" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\McNeel\#####ceros\4.0\[#####4.RECENT]\Plug-ins\FCAF502A-1572-42a9-A2C3-F25D7953B1A5" Name="FileName" Action="write" Type="string" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]##############\##############Server.rhp" />
                <RemoveRegistryKey Id="##############Skin" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\McNeel\#####ceros\4.0\Scheme: ##############" Action="removeOnInstall" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="VRayKeys" Guid="{96E9EBAC-48B4-4517-9409-F921BE92B3AA}" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" NeverOverwrite="yes">
                <RegistryValue Id="VRayKey" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\##############\Data" Name="Data" Action="write" Type="string" Value="FFFAAA" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="VRayRegistryKeys" Guid="{4D8815FA-85E2-421f-8BF9-F7F5A4133E96}" DiskId="1" KeyPath="yes" NeverOverwrite="yes" Permanent="yes">
                <Condition>
                    NOT VRAYCOMMONDIR
                </Condition>
                <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="Software\ASGvis" Name="common_dir" Action="write" Type="string" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]VRay\ASGVIS" />
            </Component>
        </Directory>
        <Feature Id="##############Features" Title="#####" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="##############" />
            <ComponentRef Id="##############LibraryUserPermissions" />
            <ComponentRef Id="##############SharedUserPermissions" />
            <ComponentRef Id="##############RegistryKeys" />
            <ComponentRef Id="VRayRegistryKeys" />
            <ComponentRef Id="VRayKeys" />
            <ComponentRef Id="ProgramMenuShortcuts" />
            <ComponentRef Id="#####App" />
            <ComponentRef Id="WixShortCut" />
            <ComponentRef Id="##############ShortCut" />
            <ComponentRef Id="TroubleShortCut" />
            <ComponentRef Id="DesktopShortcut" />
            <ComponentRef Id="VRayAuth" />
            <ComponentRef Id="Fonts" />
        </Feature>
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
        <UI />
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Icon Id="ShortCutIcon" SourceFile="D:\##############Stage\Input_WIX\NonHeat\##############.exe" />
        <Icon Id="TroubleShooterIcon" SourceFile="D:\##############Stage\Input_WIX\Heat\TroubleShooter\TroubleShooter.exe" />
        <Icon Id="TeamViewerIcon" SourceFile="D:\##############Stage\Input_WIX\Heat\support.exe" />
        <DirectoryRef Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Component Id="ProgramMenuShortcuts" Guid="881BD571-4FAF-4aa4-AB6E-15BB1629BE06">
                <CreateFolder Directory="ProgramMenuDir" />
                <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveMenuShortcuts" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" On="uninstall" />
                <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\##############\##############ShortCut" Name="InstalledStartMenuShortcuts" Type="integer" Value="1" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
        <!-- This file is not Heat'ed, so we need this to install the executable -->
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLLOCATION" FileSource="Files">
            <Component Id="##############App" Guid="FA41A015-7D80-4e50-A909-94BBA4D7546A">
                <File Id="#####_Executable" Vital="yes" Source="D:\##############Stage\Input_WIX\NonHeat\##############.exe" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLLOCATION" FileSource="Files">
            <Component Id="WixShortCut" Guid="{8F2596B8-B7EC-4f40-AD64-DFC182A9353A}">
                <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\##############\##############ShortCut" Action="create">
                    <RegistryValue Name="ShortCut" Value="1" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
                </RegistryKey>
                <Shortcut Id="ProgramMenuApplicationShortcut" Name="##############" Target="[###############_Executable]" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Show="normal" Icon="ShortCutIcon" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLLOCATION">
            <Component Id="TroubleShortCut" Guid="{9E960528-8798-41DD-8DEE-9C3336CD3C88}">
                <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\#####\#####ShortCut" Action="create">
                    <RegistryValue Name="ShortCut2" Value="1" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
                </RegistryKey>
                <Shortcut Id="TroubleshooterStartmenuShortcut" Name="Troubleshooter" Target="[INSTALLLOCATION]TroubleShooter\TroubleShooter.exe" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Icon="TroubleShooterIcon" Show="normal"></Shortcut>
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLLOCATION">
            <Component Id="TeamViewerShortCut" Guid="{AD99CAC6-E485-444B-B075-2FD8BE4C87A8}">
                <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\#####\#####ShortCut" Action="create">
                    <RegistryValue Name="ShortCut3" Value="1" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
                </RegistryKey>
                <Shortcut Id="TeamviewerStartmenuShortcut" Name="Remote Assistance" Target="[INSTALLLOCATION]support.exe" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Icon="TeamViewerIcon" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLLOCATION" FileSource="Files">
            <Component Id="DesktopShortcut" Guid="{EA9632D1-08ED-4257-A78F-B2373A65A5CF}">
                <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\#####\##############ShortCut" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                    <RegistryValue Name="desktopShortcut" Value="1" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes" />
                </RegistryKey>
                <Shortcut Id="DesktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="#####" Icon="ShortCutIcon" Target="[######_Executable]" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
        <DirectoryRef Id="FontsFolder">
            <Component Id="Fonts" Guid="{8C8EE16C-92B6-4926-A41C-55B79429071C}" NeverOverwrite="yes">
                <File Id="bradley" Source="Fonts\bradhitc.ttf" TrueType="yes" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="#####4.SYSTEM">
            <Component Id="VRayAuth" Guid="{ABED80D1-6EBA-48db-83E0-7CF48B0A55E8}">
                <File Id="VRayAuthFile" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\..\Libraries\VRayAuth.dll" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Heath Stewart's [Introducing Managed Bootstrapper Applications](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/introducing-managed-bootstrapper-applications/) provides a basic example in his blog.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a separate WiX bootstrapper project. See [Building Installation Package Bundles](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm) in the WiX 3.6 documentation.

Comment: The document BryanJ mentioned was installed with Wix 3.6. You can find it in your windows start menu.

Comment: Sorry, I do not to want be rude, but the official documentation is almost useless. It misses a minimal example or a link to a working sample.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have your bootstrapper, all you need to do is:

1. Add a reference to the file `WixNetFxExtension.dll` into your bootstrapper / managed bootstrapper application project.
2. Add the following as the first item in your chain.

   ```
   <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Web"/>
   ```

That's it. Further information and options are in [the WixNetfxExtension documentation](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm).

Comment: He doesn't have a chain so I don't see how this is helpful.

Comment: Personally I would argue it *is* helpful, as the chosen answer by the op would by definition require a chain (in fact all answers relate to bootstrappers). Once you have your bootstrapper as in KMoraz's link, adding the pre-requisite required is as simple as adding the PackageGroupRef line.

Comment: The tricky part is the bootstrap, not the reference.I don´t consider this as an apropriated answer.