# How to change icon in UAC prompt of signed installer (WiX)?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uac, wix3.5

I'm creating an msi package with WiX 3.5 (VS2010) and everything is fine, except that I don't know how to set my icon in UAC prompt. I already have a signing certificate and know how to sign with "signtool.exe" to get the publisher information and app description on UAC prompt, but I can't change the default icon and can't find any info on how to do this.

My WiX script contains lines:

```
<Icon Id="MyApp.ico" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)Libraries\Images\MyApp.ico" />
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="MyApp.ico" />
```

but I guess this works only for Add/Remove programs menu.

Here is how my UAC looks now (sorry for Russian):[image: UAC prompt with default icon]

Comment: Try reading this article: http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/icon-not-displaying-uac-when-installinguninstalling

Comment: Im late but you can use a wix bootstrapper VS Project, this way you can display your icon in UAC. Its work but answers your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021189/a-complete-wix-3-6-bundle-example-bootstrapping-a-net-4-client-profile

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MSI files don't have an icon like an executable does, so you can't customize the icon on this dialog. What you're seeing is the icon for the calling process (I think) which is msiexec.exe and is used to execute MSI files.

Comment: Incredible: I tried Google Chrome, Media Player Classic and Tortoise SVN official MSI packages and this seems to be true - all of them show the same default icon. It's pretty stupid and gives me an idea why a lot of big software developers use something other than MSI, at least for the default packages...

Comment: Pretty much all "big developers" use MSI, as it's the standard for  deploying software across a business. i.e. If you're going to make it big you're going to have to sell your software, and most businesses buying more than say 50 licenses are going to demand MSI.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. By "default package" I meant something that lays under big button "DOWNLOAD" on the main page of the website.