# Sample application for WiX bootstrapper (check .NET Framework and SQL Server 2005/ 2008)

Tags: wix, wix3.6

What would be a [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) bootstrapper sample?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and WiX 3.6 Beta.

I want to make the setup to check prerequisites [.NET Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4 and [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) (any version).

Comment: Have you read [this section](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm) of the WiX manual? Also, I suppose it can be more up-to-date in WiX.chm file you get when the WiX toolset is installed

Comment: yes i read it. but i am not got it.

Comment: Same question that was answered here perhaps?

[Can someone provide a complete Wix 3.6 Bundle example bootstrapping .Net 4 Client Profile][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021189/can-someone-provide-a-complete-wix-3-6-bundle-example-bootstrapping-net-4-clien

Answer (score 0):

There's a VERY simple example here http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm